# convert iframe document into parent document

Tags: javascript, iframe

Sorry for the rough title. I have an iframe into my document. I want that on some event the iframe destroys itself becoming the parent (main) document. For example, running the following code

```
var el = document.createElement("iframe");
el.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
document.body.appendChild(el);
el.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.gmail.com');
```

after a while or after the login the iframe disappears and takes the place of the main document. How can I obtain the same behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a [framekiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller)

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is possible through some complex javascript hacks, I don't know if this would be desirable. What happens if the user hits the back button, are you now going to try and put everything back in an iframe and restore your original document?

I think, to keep with the way most people are used to and the most usable way, it is best to redirect the parent window to the src url that you desire to go to.

Also, once a user navigates somewhere in an iframe, you will no longer know where the user is at unless it is on your same domain. This is a security restriction, and there is no way around it.

how about this?

```
//From inside the iframe to set parent to gmail.com
window.top.location.assign('http://www.gmail.com')

//From inside the iframe to set parent to the current iframe location
window.top.location.assign(window.location.href)

//From the parent document to gmail.com
window.location.assign('http://www.gmail.com')

//From the parent document to the iframe location (if iframe is same domain)
window.location.assign(window.frames[0].location.href)
```